# Why ClipToBounds = false not work?

Tags: c#, wpf

I do not want cut text of textblock. For this reason, I set viewBox.ClipToBounds to false, But it doesn't work.

Please tell me why ClipToBounds=false not work in this code:

```
   private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Button button = new Button(); button.Background = Brushes.Red;
            button.Width = 70; button.Height = 20;
            Canvas.SetLeft(button, 100); Canvas.SetTop(button, 120);
            button.Padding = new Thickness(1);

            StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

            Viewbox viewBox = new Viewbox();
             viewBox.ClipToBounds = false;

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
             canvas.Width = button.Width; canvas.Height = button.Height;

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "this is a test";
            textBlock.FontSize = 15;
            textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
            textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            textBlock.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            viewBox.Height = 20;
            textBlock.IsHitTestVisible = false;

            stackPanel.Children.Add(viewBox);
            viewBox.Child = canvas;
            canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);
            button.Content = stackPanel;

            Canvas MainCanvas = new Canvas();
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(button);
            this.Content = MainCanvas;
    }
```

Screenhsot:

[image]

The screenshot below is what I want. :
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what happens? Probably has something to do with wrapping or the width.

Comment: Sorry , I don't have enough reputation for send image.

Comment: Upload your screenshot to one of the many free image hosters (such as [imgur.com](http://www.imgur.com) for example) then add the link to the screenshot to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
 Screenshot Has been sent.

Comment: `button.Width = 70`... that clips your text. Note that setting *ClipToBounds* for the ViewBox only concerns the clipping with regard to the parent of the ViewBox - which is the stack panel -, but it will not affect the clipping with regard to any of parents of the stack panel (such as the button)...

Comment: I set button size to its parent also I set ClipToBounds to false for all elements ,But it didn't work.

Comment: Note that the button with the text is a child of "MainCanvas". "MainCanvas" will be set as the content of "this". "this" is the object/control/panel where you implemented the "Btn1_Click" method. Note that this control will also affect clipping as well as its parent controls... To see what is going on, set the (background) colors for the involved controls to different colors -- this will make it easy for you to see which controls have which actual sizes and how this would affect clipping...

Answer (score 4):

`ClipToBounds` is `false` by default. However, clipping can still happen due to the way certain elements perform layout. Basically the way things work in WPF is that setting `ClipToBounds = true` will force things to clip. Leaving it set to `false` means that WPF determines how things should clip based on measure constraints and arrange rects.

If you look at the `ArrangeCore` and `MeasureCore` methods in [`FrameworkElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs), you will see that there is quite a bit of logic determining whether something should clip. Of course, things that override `FrameworkElement` are free to render however they want, but generally they will obey the clipping rules established by the base class.

In the case of a `TextBlock`, it will definitely clip text that goes outside of its bounds if its size is constrained. You can see this by simply setting a `Width` on it, or placing it is a parent that has a `Width` set on it.

If you really need the text to render outside of the bounds of the control, you may have to consider something like writing a custom text rendering element.
 Even then, it is still going to be clipped by its parent as soon as you place it in something else that clips. So, you could still end up stuck.

You could try placing the `TextBlock` on top of the button instead of inside of it, and setting its position to get it in the right place (maybe by binding it to something). This would work, but might get hard to manage if you need to do it too much.

Basically, you are trying to go against one of the hard-coded rules of WPF, so you are likely not going to find an easy way to do it. Perhaps you might want to reevaluate your design and determine if this behavior is really necessary for what you want to do, or if you can go about it in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to elgonzo and Xavier.

I realized that I should not put the canvas in the viewbox.

By 2 change my problem solved.

1 - Swap viewbox with canvas.

2 - Remove `canvas.with = ...`

This is correct code :

```
 private void Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = new Button(); button.Background = Brushes.Red;
        button.Width = 70; button.Height = 20;
        Canvas.SetLeft(button, 100); Canvas.SetTop(button, 120);
        button.Padding = new Thickness(1);

        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

        Viewbox viewBox = new Viewbox();
        viewBox.ClipToBounds = false;

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
       // canvas.Width = button.Width; canvas.Height = button.Height;

        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Text = "this is a test";
        textBlock.FontSize = 15;
        textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        textBlock.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        viewBox.Height = 20;
        textBlock.IsHitTestVisible = false;

        stackPanel.Children.Add(canvas);
        viewBox.Child = textBlock;
        canvas.Children.Add(viewBox);
        button.Content = stackPanel;

        Canvas MainCanvas = new Canvas();
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(button);
        this.Content = MainCanvas;

    }
```